# Collapse one at the time on different divs

Tags: javascript, html

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.collaps');
const colls = document.querySelectorAll('.collaps_content');

buttons.forEach((thisButton, index) => {
    thisButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        colls[index].style.display !== 'none'
        ? colls[index].style.display = 'none'
        : colls[index].style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="collaps">Btn1</button>
        <button class="collaps">Btn2</button>
        <button class="collaps">Btn3</button>
        <button class="collaps">Btn4</button>
    </div>


    <div class="collaps_content" style="display: none;">
        Btn1
    </div>

    <div class="collaps_content" style="display: none;">
        Btn2
    </div>

    <div class="collaps_content" style="display: none;">
        Btn3
    </div>

    <div class="collaps_content" style="display: none;">
        Btn4
    </div>
</div>
```

Is working fine, but I only want one `collaps_content` open at a time, that part is not working.

When I click on every `button` they are all open and I don't want that to happen.

I tried to look for solutions but so far none worked.

Comment: Did you mean you want the current collapse_content to be removed when another button is clicked? Because for me, only the collapse_content of the button I'm clicking is coming. All of them are not coming together when I click one button.

Comment: Yeess, ```the current collapse_content to be removed when another button is clicked?```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to close any other open collapsible divs when clicking a button. You can do this by first closing all collapsible divs, and then open the correct one like this:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.collaps');
const colls = document.querySelectorAll('.collaps_content');

buttons.forEach((thisButton, index) => {
    thisButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        colls.forEach(b => b.style.display = 'none');
        colls[index].style.display !== 'none'
        ? colls[index].style.display = 'none'
        : colls[index].style.display = 'block';
    });
});
```

I just added the `colls.forEach(b => b.style.display = 'none');` in your existing JS.

Comment: I'm not able to edit but do fix the typo in the snippet to  `colls.forEach(b => b.style.display = 'none');`

Comment: @vnk There you go!